# Any way to increase the memory settings for rational clearcase remote client

Tags: java, clearcase, jvm-arguments, clearcase-remote-client

I am using rational clearcase remote client Version 7.1.1.3.
Since this is an Eclipse based tool; I was trying to find out if I can increase the memory settings for minimum and maximum memory for this tool as we can do in eclipse by adding the following parameters:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
```

in eclipse.ini file.

I can not find a eclipse.ini file under my Rationa ClearCase Remote client installation location; but I do see several config.ini files in locations like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC_1\clearcase\RemoteClient\integration
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC_1\clearcase\RemoteClient\configuration
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC_1\clearcase\RemoteClient
```

I am not sure which one to change what to change.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

the reason I want to change the settings is because, my remote client is very slow and since I have to work with huge views with heavy cleacase operations I am thinking it is because of memory usage.

my system info:
Windows 7 enterprise edition 64 bit
IBM installation manager 1.4.4
IBM rational ClearCase Client 7.1.1.03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the **`ccrc.ini`** file (if using ClearCase Remote Client stand-alone application) for example `<ClearCase Installed Directory>\clearcase\RemoteClient\ccrc.ini`

See the technote "[Improving ClearCase Remote Client (CCRC) performance](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21499919)".

`eclipse.ini` is only involved if you install CCRC as a plugin to an existing Eclipse.

That is through `ccrc.ini` that you can:

- [enable debug tracing](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21423940)
- [Fix module path](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21394810)
- and so on...

Windows-like path:  `C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\RemoteClient\ccrc.ini`
Unix-like path: `/opt/ibm/RationalSDLC/clearcase/RemoteClient/ccrc.ini`

Comment: The link seems to be perfect. I will change the setting and give it a try. Thanks